# Little issue when printing a couple of strings using perl

Tags: perl

I have this snippet;

```
print "$score\n";
for (my $i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
{
print $output[$i];
if($i == $center)
{
    print "*";
}
print "\n";
}
```

and it should print this:

```
-62
ttagggcccgg-a-tc---attaccgggc--caa
tta--gcgcgg-attcg-gatta-cggg---c-a*
gcg--gggcggcattagcaattt-gggg-atc-a
-ta--gcgc---a-----aataa-ccgg------
```

but instead it prints this:

```
-62
ttagggcccgg-a-tc---attaccgggc--caa
*ta--gcgcgg-attcg-gatta-cggg---c-a
gcg--gggcggcattagcaattt-gggg-atc-a
-ta--gcgc---a-----aataa-ccgg------
```

If i remove the "*", the strings are correct (they are really the strings i want to print), the problem is its placing. this is printed:

```
-62
ttagggcccgg-a-tc---attaccgggc--caa
tta--gcgcgg-attcg-gatta-cggg---c-a
gcg--gggcggcattagcaattt-gggg-atc-a
-ta--gcgc---a-----aataa-ccgg------
```

Why is it printing on the beginning of the string, and not on te end as it is supposed to?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I suspect that's not your actual code as it would be impossible to print a `*` without it being followed by a newline.

Comment: It is, i used copy and paste, just inserted some spaces to get the code showed correctly.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a stray carriage return (Ctrl+M) somewhere? A `print "^M*"` (where `^M` is a literal CR) would produce the output you're seeing but your editor might not be displaying it properly.

Comment: @polar - Had to figure out how your input was mangled to produce that :) See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works perfectly on a *nix system where `\n` is the only line terminator and the lines of text in `@output` do not end in `\n`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @output = ("ttagggcccgg-a-tc---attaccgggc--caa",
              "tta--gcgcgg-attcg-gatta-cggg---c-a",
              "gcg--gggcggcattagcaattt-gggg-atc-a",
              "-ta--gcgc---a-----aataa-ccgg------");

my $center = 1;
my $score = -62;

print "$score\n";
for (my $i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
{
    print $output[$i];
    if($i == $center)
    {
        print "*";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
-62
ttagggcccgg-a-tc---attaccgggc--caa
tta--gcgcgg-attcg-gatta-cggg---c-a*
gcg--gggcggcattagcaattt-gggg-atc-a
-ta--gcgc---a-----aataa-ccgg------
```

The only way I see your code generating the output you post is if each line of text contained in `@output` ends with a `\r` which would cause the carriage return to occur, then you'd print the `*` (which would overwrite the first character of the line you just output) followed by the `\n` at the bottom of your loop.

If I change `@output` in my example to:

```
my @output = ("ttagggcccgg-a-tc---attaccgggc--caa\r",
              "tta--gcgcgg-attcg-gatta-cggg---c-a\r",
              "gcg--gggcggcattagcaattt-gggg-atc-a\r",
              "-ta--gcgc---a-----aataa-ccgg------\r");
```

Then the output is:

```
-62
ttagggcccgg-a-tc---attaccgggc--caa
*ta--gcgcgg-attcg-gatta-cggg---c-a
gcg--gggcggcattagcaattt-gggg-atc-a
-ta--gcgc---a-----aataa-ccgg------
```

SO the final answer is: Get rid of the `\r` at the end of those. :)

**Edit:** As TLP points out in the comments below, using a regex substitution to make sure that there's nothing on the end of those lines should fix you up:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
{
    $output[$i] =~ s/\s*$//;
    print $output[$i];
    ...
```

**Last Edit:** From the comments below from TLP, I would *guess* this data is read from a file that came from a windows machine where lines end in `\r\n`. When reading that file in perl on OSX, you're using `chomp` to remove newlines. In OSX, `chomp` is only going to remove `\n` (by default) and leave the `\r` intact.

Comment: That's funny. I did not see this answer when I posted mine, but it says it was posted 28 mins ago?

Comment: @TLP - Sorry, I had deleted it temporarily because I really didn't answer the question as well as I should have, and it took me a couple minutes to add the code and output. I guess it keeps the original post time

Comment: Alright, im really pissed off. Nothing appears to be working right now, even my mac screen capture crashed and won't work anymore. My friend is using an ubuntu VM and it works OK. I can't really find the problem on my mac tho..

Comment: Then I will delete my answer. You might want to include the fix `s/\s*$//` instead of `chomp`.

Comment: I set this as correct, i couldn't find the \r on my code and fix it, but that is probably the real problem as the code works on some other platforms. Indeed I wrote this using osx->windows->osx so something got screwed up somewhere.

Comment: `s/\s*$// for @output` is a nicer looking `chomp`, though. The C-style for loops are so clunky that I would almost prefer `for (@output) { s/\s*$//; print; }`, except that one'd have to fix the `$i == $center` thing manually. =)

Comment: @polar If you want to know exactly what is in your strings, I can warmly recommend using the [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Dumper) module, along with the `$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1` option set. It will print out whitespace characters, e.g. `foobar\r`.

Comment: @TLP - and actually I suspect that `chomp` wouldn't work here as `$/` on OSX should only be `\n`.

Comment: @BrianRoach Yep, that'd be the problem here. Mixing file systems. `dos2unix` might also solve the problem.

Comment: @TLP - that's the odd thing (and why I took so long with rewriting my answer) - the dos/unix thing should have ended up with the lines ending in `\r\n` which is not the case or he'd have blank lines interspersed in his output. Oh I see ... he's doing a `chomp` somewhere on those lines before he gets to this snippit, which would explain it - on OSX it would remove `\n` and leave the `\r` intact.

Comment: That last edit really made things clear, that is probably the problem i was facing. There was no \r on the code, so it was probably on the input file. Thanks a lot.